# process.env.NODE_ENV return wrong value when process.env json has the correct value

Tags: json, reactjs

process.env.NODE_ENV  return wrong value when  process.env json has the correct value. why??

process.env json  console log:

```
const jsn_text=JSON.stringify(process.env);
 console.log("JSON.parse(jsn).NODE_ENV:"+JSON.parse(jsn_text).NODE_ENV); 
 //output:  JSON.parse(jsn_text).NODE_ENV:production
```

process.env.NODE_ENV console log:

```
console.log("process.env.NODE_ENV:"+process.env.NODE_ENV);
//output:  process.env.NODE_ENV:development
```

Comment: simple caching issue restart server

Comment: reset didinot solve my problem. the output is the same

Comment: change the values in json file is it changing or not.